# Do teens have to pay tax for the funds they get from crowdfunding?

Tags: united-states, tax-law

So Kickstarter allows non-adults to start a fundraising campaign with parents agreement. But how about the taxes after they (teens) received their funds? What type of taxes does Kickstarter's funds count as. Do teens have to pay taxes for their fund (like maybe as income)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, money received from Kickstarter campaigns [is usually considered taxable income](https://www.kickstarter.com/help/taxes). Who pays the taxes and how much (if any) they pay depends on how much the teenager makes, how old they are, and whether they are claimed as a dependant by someone else. For information about taxing children see [IRS Pub. 929](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p929).

As pointed out in the comments, certain campaign contributions could be considered nontaxable "gifts" by the IRS. There are also taxable gifts but the taxes are paid and reported by the gift giver. You will want to talk to a tax professional about these. It is worth noting that interest on gifts is taxable unearned income unless the gifts were set up under a UGMA trust, which has its own rules.

You can deduct most expenses from income, as pointed out in the comments. This too is covered by Pub. 929.

Comment: As the link points out it's possible to not owe any taxes. If the Kickstarter fund is a gift then no taxes would be owed. Depending on whether the Kickstarter fund was for a project that delivered something or done simply as a gift is what will determine taxability. Gifts do not impose a tax liability on the recipient. Taxability will depend greatly on the type of fund that is started.

Comment: @DaveD then what makes a fund consider as gift?

Comment: Generally, it's a gift for tax purposes if it comes from an individual in the US and wasn't part of any larger transaction or in exchange for anything, if it was given out of generosity and a desire to help by someone who has not yet received and does not expect to receive anything in return for it. (Things get tricky if some of the donors to your campaign are foreign or are companies.)

Comment: Also, we're talking about net income.  If the teenagers get money from a Kickstarter and start spending it on fulfillment of that Kickstarter, the spent money is business expenses and doesn't count as income.